# Trying to set up Apache Virtual Server on Virtualbox

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, virtualhost

I have set up an Ubuntu 14.04 server with a Lubuntu front end in Virtualbox. I now want to configure two virtual servers on this system (something I have already done successfully on Windows). I just can't get it to work and am at my wits end. Help would be much appreciated.
Here is what I have done:

1) To make sure the my requests were not going anywhere outside the Virtualbox, I switched off the Virtualbox network, now marked as "Not attached".

2) Checked the Apache server on `http://localhost`to make sure that Apache is up and running and able to serve a page. It works.

3) Modified /etc/hosts to include: `127.0.0.1     economie`. Tried `ping -a economie`. This works and shows IP address 127.0.0.1

4) Installed webmin and set up a Virtual Server called "economie" with the following characteristics:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName economie
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/economie
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

5) Checked that the Virtual Server shows up in Webmin (it does)

6) Configured Firefox to use No Proxy

7) Try to navigate to `http://economie`. Firefox displays an error page "Server not found".

Please somebody, what on earth have I done wrong?

Comment: Could you test if adding `127.0.0.1 economie www.economie` in `/etc/hosts` fix your problem? Don't forget to press F5 to reload page.

Comment: @Letizia Tried this - including completely deleting Firefox cache and also adding ServerAlias www.economie in the config file. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I got this to work by **religiously** following [the instructions here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts). I realised in particular, looking at the default Apache page on localhost, that Apache seems to be set **only** to serve pages from a directory called public_html. Definitely a case of RTFM